# About dual table structure in Oracle SQL *Plus

Tags: sql

We know that "Dual" is a temporary table which exactly contains 1 column whose name is "dummy"  which is of "varchar2(1)" type that has 1 single row. The value of that record is "X". The varchar2 has size of 1 which means it should not allow more than a single character. 
Now my question is: If it is of varchar2 type, then why it can hold any datatype temporarily AND If we insert characters more than 1 (size), how this is possible for it (dual) to accept it ? Example:

```
SQL> desc dual

 Name                            Null?    Type
 ------------------------------- -------- ----
 DUMMY                                    VARCHAR2(1)

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
22-JAN-13

SQL> select 5*5 result from dual;

   RESULT
---------
       25

SQL> select 'Ankita' as "Name" from dual;

Name
------
Ankita
```

Clearly "SYSDATE" is of DATE type (not varchar2), "RESULT" is of NUMBER type (not varchar2). Also 'Ankita' is more than 1 single character, i.e., 6 characters. This should contradict the structure that varchar2 is holding only 1, and supporting 6 too..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/435/how-does-the-oracle-dual-table-work

Comment: None of your statements actually *change* the value of the dummy table. You are confusing selecting (constant) values with updating a column's value.

Comment: You're not selecting `Dummy` from `Dual`, so its structure is irrelevant.

Comment: @satya- From your given link, another query. "From the documentation (CONCEPTS): The dual table is useful when a value must be returned only once, for example, the current date and time. All database users have access to DUAL.

The DUAL table has one column called DUMMY and one row containing the value X." We can insert more than 1 column. Try this: SQL>select sysdate,'Ankita' "Name" from dual;

Comment: @ankitaP - the number of columns in a table is completely unrelated to the number and type of columns in the `SELECT` clause. Imagine you have a table (`tab`) containing two columns, `x` and `y`, both of type `int`. There's nothing stopping you from doing `SELECT x,y,CAST(x+y as float) as z FROM tab`. Wow! 3 columns. And the third isn't of type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The types and sizes of columns only come into play when you extract the data from them. It's true that if you `select` the `dummy` column, it will only give you what is *in* that column.

But, when you're selecting something *unrelated* to the column data, such as `5*5` or `'Ankita'`, they have no such restrictions.

I think your misunderstanding stems from your snippet:

> why it can hold any datatype temporarily AND If we insert characters more than 1 (size), how this is possible for it (dual) to accept it ?

The truth is, the column *doesn't* accept it. Selecting `5*5` does *not* attempt to place that data into the table somewhere, it just evaluates it as-is. It's no different to having a table with:

```
users:
    id
    name
```

and performing:

```
select 42, 3.14159, id, name from users
```

For every row selected from, you will see the constant values `42` and `3.14159`, alongside the data extracted from the two specified columns.